# Непонятные отступы в TextArea

Tags: html, css

Есть форма [тут.](http://easymoney.website.com.kz/task/addnew) При клике на textarea появляются странные отступы слева и сверху. Почему?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: судя по всему, автозаполнение пробелами при открытии страницы для создания "отступов"

Comment: Вопросы-ссылки недопустимы на StackOverflow на русском, так как вся их ценность будет утеряна в случае, если ссылка станет нерабочей.Пожалуйста, приведите [минимально воспроизводимый пример кода](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) **прямо в вопросе**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Всё в норме. У вас внутри textarea между тегами куча пробелов и перенос строки

`<textarea name="discription">
            
        </textarea>`